# Modern graduate-level machine learning books

Tags: machine-learning, references

I'm looking for a modern machine learning book with graduate-level treatment of more recent topics such as diffusion and generative models, transformers etc.

I have a hard copy of *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow and Bengio; while I liked the book and read it extensively when it was published, it is a bit dated now.

I'm considering *[Probabilistic Machine Learning: Advanced Topics](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book2.html)* by Kevin Patrick Murphy. But maybe there are better alternatives.

I need this for my comprehensive Phd examination. Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: Machine learning in general or deep learning in particular?

Comment: In particular diffusion, generative and transformer topics

Comment: @MonteNero I don't know whether it will be useful for you, but I found [Foundations of Machine Learning by
Mehryar Mohri](https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/) is the better option than the book by Murphy. I guess it's more rigour and it was simpler for me to find what I wanted in that book than in the book by Murphy.  But it's more about Machine learning in general than about the SOTA models.

Comment: I cannot recommend something on these topics (diffusion models, generative models and transformers) by myself but I heard recommendations for the courses [Advanced Deep Learning for Computer Vision: Visual Computing (ADL4CV)](https://niessner.github.io/ADL4CV/) and [CAP6412 Advanced Computer Vision](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLd3hlSJsX_In7qup928HaHmilugBGctuF) to learn about these topics.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good graduate-level textbooks that are available.

For a broad and advanced overview of ML topics, check out Kevin Murphy's new Probabilisitic Machine Learning [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262048434).

Another resource is Christopher Bishops new Deep Learning [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3031454677).

I am also the author of [The Variational Book](https://www.thevariationalbook.com/), a focus on variational inference and generative algorithm theory, both of which are central to learning machine learning. I provide step by step derivations of many important concepts, ideas and theorems.